# Android virtual device(HELP)

Tags: android-emulator

When i click to start my android virtual device it tells me that: invalid command-line parameter: Files\Android\android-sdk\tools/emulator-arm.exe.
Hint: use '@foo' to launch a virtual device named 'foo'.
please use -help for more information
PLEASE HELP ME

Answer (score 0):

please check whether your path is correct Files\Android\android-sdk\tools\emulator-arm.exe

or download a again that android-sdk & give new sdk path.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CtVj88QM8HE

; )